# How do I execute other code on a browser.wait timeout?

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am currently using Protractor to check that data on a page loads.  *Sometimes* the content on the page takes too long to load, so in this case, I want to perform some other actions, and then check if it is there again.

```
return browser.wait(protractor.until.elementLocated(dataRow));
```

The code above executes perfectly, however, I want something like:

```
return browser.wait(protractor.until.elementLocated(dataRow), 
        button.click();
        then check for element's presence again);
```

Any suggestions in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to click the button once? Or, should this work in a recursive manner until the `dataRow` is present? Thanks.

Comment: The button just needs to be clicked once, if the data hasn't been loaded on the page.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just put the additional code into the `browser.wait()`'s error callback:

```
return browser.wait(protractor.until.elementLocated(dataRow)).then(function () {}, function () {
    button.click();
    return browser.wait(protractor.until.elementLocated(dataRow));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Would this always execute the .then statement? As I only want to execute the function if the first browser.wait fails.   I will test your answer to see the result.

Comment: @fuzzii I've changed the answer after posting. I think you should click and return from inside the outer browser.wait()'s error callback function.

Comment: This seems to result in the error:  Failed: Cannot read property 'button' of undefined, I think that this is because this wait already timed-out, so the other code after this block continues.

Comment: @fuzzii okay, but where have you defined the button variable?..sounds like it is just not defined at this point..

Comment: I have defined it at the top of my class, outside of the function
private button: protractor.ElementFinder = $('#button');

Comment: It is definitely defined as I can take the button.click() outside of the .then() function, and the button clicks.